# Plotting gamma probability density function

Tags: r, probability

I'm trying to plot the gamma probability density function in R where y∈(0,10) for (k = 1,μ = 1), (k = 2, μ = 1), (k = 2, μ = 2). In R,

In R, the pgamma function accepts:

```
pgamma(q, shape, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, alpha = shape, beta = scale, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
```

In R, i tried:

```
pgamma(1,1,rate=1,scale = 1/rate, alpha = shape, beta = scale, lower.tail = True, log.p = False)
```

But i get the message

```
Error in pgamma(1, 1, rate = 1, scale = 1/rate, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) : 
object 'rate' not found
```

It's my first time plotting a gamma distribution and would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: `pgamma` is the distribution function, not the density. And R is case sensitive, `True` and `False` should be all uppercase.

Comment: And `pgamma(1, 1)` is equivalent to what you seem to be doing. If you pass a value for argument `rate`, don't pass one for `scale`, it's irrelevant.

Comment: FYI the error message is because you pass `1/rate` as the scale argument, but `rate` is not defined (object not found). This is easily fixed but as Rui Barradas explains you use the wrong function anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following plots the three densities using base R graphics.

First, the parameter values you want. I am assuming your `mu` is as defined in the [Wikipedia page of the Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

```
k <- c(1, 2, 2)
mu <- c(1, 1, 2)
theta <- mu/k
```

Now, the plots.

```
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 1), type = "n")
for(i in seq_along(k))
  curve(dgamma(x, shape = k[i], scale = theta[i]), from = 0, to = 10, col = i, add = TRUE)
```

[image]